# typeof(DateTime?).Name == Nullable`1

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Using Reflection in .Net `typeof(DateTime?).Name` returns "Nullable`1".

Is there any way to return the actual type as a string. (in this case "DateTime" or "System.DateTime")

I understand that `DateTime?` is `Nullable<DateTime>`. That's besides the point, I am just looking for the type of the nullable type.

Comment: The actual type IS `Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: Take out the question mark.

Comment: Keep in mind as a test this is fine, removing the question mark in code will probably break something.

Comment: If you want to pick the generic type name by reflection, in this case you'd have to use `GetGenericArguments()[0]`, *if* it actually is a generic type every time, if not, you'd have to check it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which can help you in this case. Likely you'll end up wanting to make your own utility method because (I'm assuming) you'll be using both nullable and non-nullable types:

```
public static string GetTypeName(Type type)
{
    var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

    bool isNullableType = nullableType != null;

    if (isNullableType)
        return nullableType.Name;
    else
        return type.Name;
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetTypeName(typeof(DateTime?))); //outputs "DateTime"
Console.WriteLine(GetTypeName(typeof(DateTime))); //outputs "DateTime"
```

---

EDIT: I suspect you may also be using other mechanisms on the type, in which case you can slightly modify this to get the underlying type or use the existing type if it's non-nullable:

```
public static Type GetNullableUnderlyingTypeOrTypeIfNonNullable(this Type possiblyNullableType)
{
    var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(possiblyNullableType);

    bool isNullableType = nullableType != null;

    if (isNullableType)
        return nullableType;
    else
        return possiblyNullableType;
}
```

And that is a *terrible* name for a method, but I'm not clever enough to come up with one (I'll be happy to change it if someone suggests a better one!)

Then as an extension method, your usage might be like:

```
public static string GetTypeName(this Type type)
{
    return type.GetNullableUnderlyingTypeOrTypeIfNonNullable().Name;
}
```

or

```
typeof(DateTime?).GetNullableUnderlyingTypeOrTypeIfNonNullable().Name
```

Comment: `public static string GetTypeName(this Type type)` for extension method!

Answer (score 6):

*Chris Sinclair* code works but I rewrote it more concise.

```
public static Type GetNullableUnderlyingTypeIfNullable(Type possiblyNullableType)
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(possiblyNullableType) ?? possiblyNullableType;
    }
```

And then use it:

```
GetNullableUnderlyingTypeIfNullable(typeof(DateTime?)).Name
```

Answer (score 5):

As Pointed out by Patryk:

`typeof(DateTime?).GetGenericArguments()[0].Name`

Comment: Only problem with this, is that if in practice, it's a generically used method to get the type, this will also pull out the generic type for types like `List<int>`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair One can simply add a check to see if the type itself is `Nullable` and throw an exception, if that's the behavior you need.

Comment: @Servy: Oh for sure. I just wanted to point out to Chad one of the caveats of this since we don't necessarily know the full scope of his intended usage; didn't want it surprising him later on down the road.